# The proof of Turan's theorem via Zykov symmetrization

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

> **Lemma 1.2.7.** Among $n$-vertex $r$-partite graphs, $T_{n,r}$ is the unique graph with the maximum number of edges.

> **Theorem.** The Turan graph $T_{n,r}$ maximizes the number of edges among all
> $n$-vertex $K_{r+1}$-free graphs. It is also the unique maximizer.
>
> *Proof.* As before, let $G$ be an $n$-vertex, $K_{r+1}$-free graph with the maximum possible number of edges.
>
> We claim that if $x$ and $y$ are non-adjacent vertices, then $\deg
>  x=\deg y$. Indeed, suppose $\deg x>\deg y$. We can modify $G$ by
> removing $y$ and adding in a clone of $x$ (a new vertex $x'$ with the
> same neightborhood as $x$ but not adjacent to $x$), as illustrated
> below.
>
> [image]
>
> The resulting graph would still be $K_{r+1}$-free (since a clique
> cannot contain both $x$ and its clone) and has strictly more edges
> than $G$, thereby contradicting the assumption that $G$ has the
> maximum possible number of edges.
>
> Suppose $x$ is non-adjacent to both $y$ and $z$ in $G$. We claim that
> $y$ and $z$ must be non-adjacent. We just saw that $\deg x=\deg y=\deg
>  z$. If $yz$ is an edge, then by deleting $y$ and $z$ from $G$ and
> adding two clones of $x$, we obtain a $K_{r+1}$-free graph with one
> more edge than $G$. This would contradict the maximality of $G$.
>
> [image]
>
> Therefore, non-adjacency is an equivalence relation among vertcies of
> $G$. So the complememnt of $G$ is a union of cliques. Hence $G$ is a
> complete multipartite graph, which has at most $r$ parts since $G$ is
> $K_{r+1}$-free. Among all complete $r$-partite graphs, the Turan graph
> $T_{n,r}$ is the unique graph that maximizes the number of edges, by
> Lemma 1.2.7. Therefore, $G$ is isomorphic to $T_{n,r}$.

I understand the general idea of the proof but I'd like to clarify some moments.

**Question 1.** Assume that $V(G)=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. The relation $v_i\sim v_j \Leftrightarrow v_iv_j\notin E(G)$ is an equivalence realtion on $V(G)$. Since any equivalence relation on set forms its partition, then $V(G)=V_1\sqcup \dots\sqcup V_N$, where $V_i$ are equivalence classes. More precisely, each $V_i$ is an independent set and for any $a\in V_i$, $b\in V_j$ with $i\neq j$ there is an edge connecting $a$ and $b$. It means that $G$ is complete $N$-partite graph. Is my reasoning correct here? I do not see the point why the author says that the complement of graph is a bunch of cliques.

**Question 2.** We know that initially $G$ is $n$-vertex, $K_{r+1}$-free graph with the maximum number of edges and we were able to show $G$ is complete, $N$-partite graph with $N\leq r$. I am confused how the author used the Lemma to show that $G=T_{n,r}$. How to show that $N=r$ and only in this case it has the maximum number of edges?

I'd be really thankful for help! Thank you so much!

Comment: For 2, an $N$-partite graph with $N < r$ is also an $r$-partite graph, just where some of the independent sets are empty

Comment: @jacob, by $r$-partite graph usually we mean the graph which has exactly $r$ nonempty vertex sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1)**
Yes. You are correct. It's maybe a bit easier visually to think of cliques as being equivalence classes (and is a common example to think about), so that may be why the author chose to phrase it in terms of complement.

**Question 2)**
The main theorem proof shows that $G$ is $r$-partite. As pointed out by jacob in the comments - this means it has *at most* $r$ maximal independent sets. As you've noticed, it could in theory have fewer from the proof thus far.

What the Lemma is really saying, with this understanding of what $r$-partite means is: among all $n$-vertex complete multipartite graphs with $r$ *or fewer* partite sets, $T_{n,r}$ is the unique edge maximiser. We know $G$ is $r$-partite with $n$ vertices, and maximises the edge count, so it is $T_{n,r}$ by the Lemma. I.e., the Lemma tells you $N=r$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I'd like to clarify some moments: first of all, I always thought that by $r$-partite graph we mean the graph which has exactly $r$ non-empty parts because it actually makes sense.

Comment: The lemma 1.2.7. says that $T_{n,r}$ has the maximal number of edges among all $n$-vertex $r$-partite graphs (here by $r$-partite graph I mean the graph which has exactly $r$ non-empty parts.) I remember the proof of this lemma. If we want to prove it for graphs with $r$ or fewer partite sets, then I cannot prove in this case.. since I ran into some obstacles.

Comment: @ZFR, no to your first comment. For example, a graph with no edges and lots of vertices is still "bipartite", even though you can fit all the vertices in one independent set. If your complete multipartite graph has *fewer* than $r$ partite sets, you can show it *doesn't* maximise the number of edges among $r$-partite complete multipartite graphs: just take a partite set, cut it in half, and add all the possible edges between the two halves. You now have a graph with one more part, and more edges. This proves that your maximiser (here, $T_{n,r}$) must have exactly $r$ partite sets, no less.

Comment: I agree with the example which you've provided? But what is the point of this example?

Comment: The example with no edges has 1 partite set, but we still say it's bipartite (i.e., 2-partite). We do the same thing in general - a graph that can be partition into $k$ independent sets is $k$-partite. It's also $r$-partite for any $r > k$.

Comment: You said that "take a partite set, cut it in half, and add all the possible edges between the two halves". I am bit confused here. What if each partite set has 1 vertex? How to cut in this case?

Comment: @ZFR If you have $n\leq r$ this whole problem is trivial since the complete graph $K_n$ will be $K_r$-free - Turan's Theorem isn't relevant here. If $n>r$, and you have fewer than $r$ partite sets, you'll always have a partite set with at least 2 vertices by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: You mentioned Turan's theorem in your previous comment but we are talking about the lemma. I am just trying to understand why this lemma is true in the "new" definition of multipartite graph.

Comment: @ZFR The Lemma also does not make sense and does not apply if $n<r$.

Comment: I think that I comletely got the idea behind the proof. It was much simpler than I thought before. The idea is the following: any $m$-partite graph with $m\leq r$ can be considered as $r$-partite graph also (possible with some empty vertex sets). Regarding your previous comment: I think you are not right technically since if $n<r$, then lemma makes sense because the family of all $n$-vertex, $r$-partite graphs is the same as the family of all $n$-vertex, $n$-partite graphs is the same. So it basically reduces to the case $r=n$. Does it make sense?

Comment: So in the lemma one can assume that $n\geq r$.

Comment: Can you confirm my last two comments please? Especially i am interested in the case $n<r$ which I explained above. I am about to assign bounty but I need to know is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I've replied in chat, I think it's best to keep future messages there.

Comment: I did not receive any new reply from you regarding my last comments in the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138354/discussion-between-zfr-and-brandon-du-preez).